# I am coding an andriod application, can I control homescreen app layout via my application?

Tags: java, android, system

I am devloping an andriod app in java, I want to be able to change the positioning of other apps on the phone home screen.
For example:

Youtube is currently in the top right position of the first screen and I want to be able to move it to the middle left position on the 3rd screen of the phone.

Is there a way to do this?

I haven't been able to find any APIs to do this but I am completley new to andriod app development so I doubt I have been looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this?

No, unless your app is the home screen. Home screens do not have to show icons at all, let alone provide APIs for third-party apps to control where those icons appear.